# python3 -m http.server not outputting anything

Tags: python, server

Need to set up a local server to test out my webpage.But the command is not working and does not give any error message.I can't access http://localhost:8000/ too.
[image: As shown]

Comment: `python` and `python3` are two different commands. if you type `python3 -V` what do you get? Perhaps just try `python -m http.server 8000`?

Comment: Please share that output as text, not an as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in the comments, it looks like your PATH variable is mixed up between the commands `python` (normally used for Python 2) and `python3`. You can see that `python` is actually pointing to Python 3 based on your result of `python -V`, so I would just go with that.

If you want to use `python3` as the command for Python 3, the answer depends on how you honestly set up `python` to be Python 3, but some tips would be:

- Reinstall Python 3
- Create an alias in your shell profile (`alias python3="python"`)